# Get next item in list. At the end go back to the beginning

Tags: python

I want to find next element in list. In the end of list go to start and take element with 0 index.
So it runs in infinite loop.

```
my_list = [5, 1, 2, 7, 9, 10]  # all values are unique
while True:
    for item in my_list:
        current_item = my_list[my_list.index(item)]
        try:
            next_item = my_list[my_list.index(item) + 1]
        except IndexError:
            next_item = my_list[0]
        print (current_item, next_item)
```

Can it be done without try/except?

Comment: This would work well and is already short. I don't think there is any need to change it and I would recommend keeping it like this

Comment: Please explain the use-case.  You could drop the `for` loop and use a manual counter, and index into the list with the current counter’s value, then reset the counter if greater than the list’s length.  This would also make it easy to get the next element ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to loop through the items forever you can do it easily like this:

```
mylist = [5, 1, 2, 7, 9, 10]
while True:
    for (i,x) in enumerate(mylist):
        ci = x
        ni = mylist[(i+1)%len(mylist)]
        print(ci,ni)
```

Answer (score 8):

If you want to iterate over a list repeatedly, cycling back to the first item when you reach the end, use `itertools.cycle()`.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done like this too

````
l = [5, 1, 2, 7, 9, 10]

curIndex = 0
l_len = len(l)

while True:
    if curIndex >= l_len:
        curIndex = curIndex - l_len
    print(l[curIndex])
    curIndex += 1```
````

Answer (score 1):

Yes. For example, you can use `len` to do this, but @ThePilotDude is right.

```py
my_list = [5, 1, 2, 7, 9, 10]
while True:
    for i in range(0, len(my_list)): # Loop 1 - length of my_list times
        current_item = my_list[i]
        if i + 1 < len(my_list):
            next_item = my_list[i + 1]
        else:
            print(current_item, my_list[0])
            break
        print(current_item, next_item)
```

Similar to what you had.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution:

```
my_list = [5, 1, 2, 7, 9, 10]
while True:
    for index,current in enumerate(my_list):
        next_index = (index+1)%len(my_list)
        next_item=my_list[next_index]
        print (current, next_item)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
my_list = [5, 1, 2, 7, 9, 10]

for item in range(len(my_list)):
    if(item == len(my_list) - 1):
        break
    current_item = my_list[item]
    next_item = my_list[item+1]
    print (current_item, next_item)
```

It continues infinite times because of the while loop. It can be like this.